# How to play an mp3 file from server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mp3

I want to play an mp3 file that is stored in a server 
Ex:-[mp3 link](http://in.orgware.in/testing/mp3/1.mp3)

I have tried the other relevant answers but i didn't get the output.
Can anyone please tell me how to play an mp3 that is stored on the web.

Comment: "I have tried the other relevant answers": what relevant answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's documentation for AVPlayer states the following:
AVPlayerplayer works equally well with local and remote media files

Apple's documentation for  AVAudioPlayer states the following:
Use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream

```
  -(IBAction)playTapped {
        AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.mp3.com/mp3file.mp3"]] retain];
        [player play];

     }
```

Comment: -(IBAction)playTapped {
 
 NSError * error = nil;
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://in.orgware.in/testing/mp3/1.mp3"];
 AVAudioPlayer * myPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url error:&error];
 if(myPlayer)
 {
  [myPlayer play];
 }
} ....I tried the code like above but i didn't get the output

Comment: @iPhone_suren so what is the problem?

Comment: @AlbrahimZ mp3 is not playing, thats the problem

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're using AVAudioPlayer instead of AVPlayer. If I remember correctly AVPlayer supports this, whereas AVAudioPlayer does not.